# Querying polygons that contain 4 points

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal, ogr

I have 4 points that I always get, I would like to query if the polygon defined by a multipoint contains those 4 points. I’m using PostGIS and Postgres.

I'm also using OGR/GDAL for that purpose. Would someone provide me with the Query using SQL for that purpose.

Comment: Please define "to lie inside 4 points".

Comment: if the polygon is within those 4 points. The 4 points are camera points, so I would like to know if that polygon is inside those 4 points, lies in the filed of view of the camera

Comment: I need polygons that contain those 4 points.

Comment: Note that I'm using GDAl 2.1 ogr. so I have to use a query that is supported by it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This checks if the points (1 1), (2 2), (3 3), and (4 4) all lie inside the polygon defined by (0 0), (10 0), (10 10), (0 10) and (0 0):

```
SELECT st_contains(
          st_polygon(
             st_linefrommultipoint(
                st_mpointfromtext(
                   'MULTIPOINT(0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0)'
                )
             ),
             0
          ),
          st_mpointfromtext(
             'MULTIPOINT(1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4)'
          )
       );
```

So to find all multipoints that satisfy the criterion, you could use something like that:

```
SELECT id
FROM multipoints
WHERE st_contains(
         st_polygon(
            st_addpoint(
               st_linefrommultipoint(
                  multipoints.geom
               ),
               st_startpoint(
                  st_linefrommultipoint(
                     multipoints.geom
                  )
               ),
               -1
            ),
            st_srid(multipoints.geom)
         ),
         st_mpointfromtext(
            'MULTIPOINT(1 1, 2 2, 3 3, 4 4)',
            8307
         )
      );
```

This assumes that the multipoints don't form a closed polygon (i.e., first point is equal to last).

I used SRID 8307 in my example, replace it with the one you need.

Comment: Thanks, I'm beginner, I can get the geometry from the column GEOM. How would I set it in the above SQL statement, I also want to select "All" polygons " from the table not only one polygon

Comment: I have extended the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: FEHLER:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries
That's what I get. 

 SELECT gid
FROM areas
WHERE st_contains(
         areas.geom,
         st_mpointfromtext(
            'MULTIPOINT(16.075 47.950, 16.249 47.914, 16.249 47.91411, 16.232 47.826)'
         )
      );

Comment: lwpoly_from_lwlines: shell must be closed

Comment: About the SRIDs - well, you must use the same for all. About not closed: the first point is not identical to the last one.

Comment: so the first point of the polygon must be the same as last one ? but I have a "predefined" polygons, which are exactly areas in 2D, how would I make the criteria then ?

Comment: I have edited the answer to match your needs more closely.

Comment: My Polygon points are : 
x = 16.07514381, double y = 47.95055008;
x = 16.24965286, y = 47.91411209;
x = 16.23201180, y = 47.82641983;
x = 16.14973259, y = 47.79749298;
x = 15.93255901, y = 47.89419937;
however your query does not return any results, however points 1,1 2,2, 3,3, 4,4 should lie into that polygon

Comment: These points do *not* lie in  the polygon. All of the coordinates are greater than 4!

Comment: is it possible to check the reverse, if the polygon lies inside the four points _

Comment: Again, define what that means.

Comment: I have a problem, I'm using https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html 
and the function St_linefrommultipoint is not available. What can I do

Comment: Use something else that allows you to write SQL.

Comment: I have used the following query which works in my client side, but not sure if its meaning is correct and it's like what you wrote ?

Comment: SELECT * from areas WHERE st_contains(ST_BuildArea(areas.geom),st_mpointfromtext('MULTIPOINT(16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549, 16.17951 47.85549)',4326));

Comment: That looks much simpler than my query (I am no PostGIS expert really). You can see if the resulting polygons look right with `st_astext`. You might want to add another answer with your solution for future reference.